# How to select each first three records of two different students from same table in single query

Tags: sql-server

I have a student table and want to find top three records of 2 students: Amy and Jack in a single query and it should be displayed according to descending marks order.

I tried using top in subquery but it did not work.

Table:

```
 Name   | Subject | Marks
 -------|---------|-------
 Tara   | English | 70
 Amy    | Maths   | 70
 Jack   | English | 80
 Amy    | Science | 80
 Amy    | English | 90
 Jack   | Maths   | 30
 Jack   | English | 50
 Tara   | Maths   | 60
 Tara   | Science | 70
```

Expected Output:

```
Amy  | English | 90
Amy  | Science | 80
Jack | English | 80 
Amy  | Maths   | 70
Jack | English | 50
Jack | Maths   | 30
```

Displaying each of their top 3 records in descending order is expected.

Comment: I'm doing a complex query for which this logic is needed. My tables are much more complex than this, they're not student tables, I just want to understand the logic and I'll work on the query on my own. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 2):

Try with ROW_NUMBER()-

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT name,
           Subject, 
           marks, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name,marks DESC
           ) RN
    FROM your_table
) A
WHERE A.RN < 4;
```

Comment: I think it should RN <=2 but thank you! This helped!

Comment: As you wants top 3 per student, < 4 or <= 3 will return your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this..

```
  ; WITH CTE AS (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY MARKS) AS SLNO,
       NAME, MARKS, SUBJECT FROM TAB
  )
  SELECT NAME, SUBJECT, MARKS FROM CTE WHERE SLNO<4 ORDER BY MARKS DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function as

```
SELECT Name,
       Subject,
       Marks
FROM(
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Marks DESC) RN
      FROM T
    ) V
WHERE RN < 4
      AND 
      Name IN ('Amy', 'Jack')
ORDER BY Marks DESC;
```

Which will gives you exactly the results you expected.

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8f09638b6a3f115173c4551b0f01783)**